# Anonymous URL pointing to file in Public GCP bucket

Tags: node.js, file, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am trying to send emails from my server these emails will contain files from a bucket in GCP. Currently the bucket holding these files is private. The issue Im facing is the file sizes are too large to send with my current setup. Ive tried compressing the files before sending but the service I use (sendgrid/mail) doesn't handle decompression atleast not that I've found.

So I have two options it seems:

1. Send a signed url to the file in my private bucket. The issue with this is Ideally access to these files would not expire and signed urls expire.
2. Make the bucket public and send the link. The issue with this approach is security, the user would have enough info in the URL to figure out viewing other files.

So my question is, is there a way to send a url to my public bucket file masked in some way to hide my bucket name? Sending a vague url that points to my actual url? Additionally any alternative approaches for a solution to this problem would be cool too. Or if Im totally off here please let me know.

(Im working in a node/express server btw)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way DNS and HTTP works, masking or proxying the bucket would still result in a connection to the host/bucket/service-endpoint to fetch the files. So trying to mask the destination host/bucket/service-endpoint a bit futile. You could change the host/bucket with a custom domain set up but the endpoint would still be resolvable and viewable by a hacker.

Another possible approach is to obfuscate the path and/or filename.

A more secure option would be to add an authentication layer (application to receive the file download request authorize it against the url parameters embedded in the download link. If it passes, have the application fetch the file from the bucket and return it to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback this is some good insight.